# Batch permission insert via Google Drive SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api

Does Google Drive SDK supports batch operation for permissions (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert)

For example, I wish to grant 20 users writer permission to a document.
Can I do it via 1 REST call instead of 20 calls?

Comment: +1 for the batch support interrogation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just come across this page : https://developers.google.com/drive/migration

At the end, we can see that batch operation are not currently supported by the drive API

Answer (score -1):

Although you can programmatically achieve that. I modified their java-script example method to achieve it this way.

```
/**
     * Retrieve a list of permissions.
     *
     * @param {String} fileId ID of the file to retrieve permissions for.
     * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
     */
    function retrievePermissions(fileId, callback) {
      var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.list({
        'fileId': fileId
      });
      request.execute(function(resp) {
        //console.log(resp);
        callback(resp.items);
      });
    }


/**
     * Update a permission's role.
     *
     * @param {String} fileId ID of the file to update permission for.
     * @param {String} permissionId ID of the permission to update.
     * @param {String} newRole The value "owner", "writer" or "reader".
     */
    function updatePermission(fileId, items,callback) {
        var updateRequest = gapi.client.drive.permissions.update({
          'fileId': fileId,
          'permissionId': items[0].id,
          'resource': items[0]
        });

        updateRequest.execute(function(resp) {
            items.splice(0,1);
            if (items.length > 0)
                updatePermission(fileId,items,callback);
            if (items.length == 0)
                callback(resp);
        });
    }
```

and to call these methods I have the following code.

```
retrievePermissions(result.id, function(items){
 var toUpdate = new Array();
 var j = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  if (items[i].role != "owner" && items[i].id != "anyoneWithLink"){
    items[i].role = "reader";
    items[i].additionalRoles = [ "commenter" ];
    toUpdate[j++] = items[i];
      }
     }

updatePermission(result.id, toUpdate, function(resp){ console.log (resp) } );
```

});

Comment: That's not batch. Here you send as many requests as permission insertion. Batch would be only one request containing every thing needed to be done.

Comment: This is not a batch request.